# increase size of legend in Performance analytics charts.Perfromance Summary

Tags: r

I have been trying to increase the size of the legend in the charts.PerformanceSummary plot.

here is my code:

```
charts.PerformanceSummary(data,geometric= FALSE,cex.axis=1.5, main="Desk Performance", legend(cex=1.5))  # I tried this but legend(cex=1.5) does not work
```

Any idea how to increase the size of the legend so I can read it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`legend(cex=1.5)` is the incorrect syntax. Use `cex.legend=1.5` instead, like so:

```
charts.PerformanceSummary(data,geometric= FALSE,cex.axis=1.5, main="Desk Performance", cex.legend=1.5)
```